# How to design an O(m) time algorithm to compute the shortest cycle of G(undirected unweighted graph) that contains s?

Tags: graph-algorithm

How to design an O(m) time algorithm to compute the shortest cycle of G(undirected unweighted graph) that contains s(s ∈ V) ?

Comment: designin an algorithm is a very broad topic. Also it is subject to opinion of different people. Someone would prefer a pure mathematical-inductive approach while someone else would prefer starting from existing algorithms and maybe do some changes. Also it is not always possible to design an algorithm with a target performance because it is possible that 1) The algorithm does not exists, 2) someone proven that the fastest algorithm is anyway slower than you want (and you really can't do anything about that). There exists an algorithm in O(number of vertices) for your problem anyway.

Comment: I guess `m` is the number of edges. What is the argument that the task is really `O(m)`? Although it's obvious that it's polynomial problem, but linearity seems less evident.

Comment: Yes, m is the number of edges. It may use BFS or DFS. But I have no idea how to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run a BFS from your node s as starting point, this will give you a BFS-tree. Afterwards you can built a lowest-common-ancestor (LCA) data structure on this BFS-tree. This can be done for example with [Tarjan's lowest-common-ancestor algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarjan%27s_off-line_lowest_common_ancestors_algorithm). I will not got into details here. Given two nodes v and w, LCA lets you find the lowest node in a tree (the BFS-tree in our case) that has v and w as descendents. The idea is when you are considering two nodes that are connected in our BFS-tree you want to check if their paths to the root (s is this case) + the edge that connects them forms a cycle (with s). This is the case if their LCA is s.

Assuming you have built the LCA, you run a second BFS. When expanding the neighbours of a node v, you also take into consideration the nodes already marked as explored. Suppose x is a neighbour of v such that x has already been explored. If the LCA of v and x is s then the path from x to s and form v to s in the BFS-tree plus the edge xv forms a cycle. The first x and v that you encounter in your second BFS gives you the desired result. If no such x exist then s is not contained in any cycle. 
The cycle is also the shortest containing s.

The two BFS run in O(m) and the LCA construction can also be done in linear time, hence the whole procedure can be implemented in O(m).

This might a bit overkill. There surely is a much simpler solution.